# How to get this particular structure with one column with list in the right?

Tags: itemize, paragraphs, columns

I'm using the article environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}

\title{TEXT}
\date{}
\maketitle 

Text: Text Text Text

\end{document}
```

How could I do something like the picture below?

[image]

(Help me with appropriated tags, please.)

Comment: `minipage`s side by side.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do the bullets.  The easiest would be to put an itemize inside a description (list environments).  Another is to use \leftskip and \llap{Text: $\bullet$}.

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you want to make an answer out of that comment?